# Communicate With Online Message Board

Tags: c++

How might one create an application that communicates to an online website's message board, say www.espn.com's message boards that can retrieve posts, post stuff, and flag posts. How might somebody go about creating an application that does something like that? sockets?

I would like to create this in c++

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Nothing. I'm looking for a general direction to kind of figure out where to start. I know winsock2 programming fairly well.. I can communicate over a network. But I am not sure how I would acquire specific data from a message board on a public website such as espn.com

Comment: Well, it's pretty dependent on the website and what they'll allow you to do. Most likely, you'll have to do some reverse engineering of their API. This isn't a thing that's generally supported.

Comment: Thank you for a response. Just curious as to if this type of deal is fairly common knowledge, or if it isn't relaly supported like you said. thanks. that's all i needed to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually more complicated than it sounds. Most message boards don't open up their API (usually to prevent spam), and if they do, you'll probably have to work with them to get the details.

The general idea is:

- Open socket to their server
- Send the appropriate data according to their API
- Profit

If you want to hack it, you'll have to do some scraping/wireshark packet sniffing to figure out their API. There will probably be some cookies you'll have to read to get communication tokens and whatnot. It's possible, but it's a lot of work.

Some other websites (like Twitter and Google) open up their API and actually provide developer tools to interact with their data. I don't think a site like ESPN would be that open to hobbyist developers, so you'd probably have to sign some kind of agreement.

If you're really interested, read up on HTTP (here's a [really simple beginning tutorial](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/)). Most APIs are built on the HTTP protocol, so you'll want to become very familiar with it. I'd recommend using something besides C++ though, since socket work can be a bit tedious. Try something like Python.